# How do I upload videos and tag photos using Facebook for Android?

Tags: facebook

How do you upload a video to Facebook from the Droid and how do you tag photos from your phone on Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do either using the official Facebook for Android app.  You have to do it through the website (presumably the full non-mobile site; there's a "Full Site" link at the bottom of the mobile version).